# Jenkins error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'node' found among steps ...."

Tags: java, maven, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

the groovy script starts with

```
node {
    stage("Checkout"){
        echo "git checkout"
        checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [
```

This `groovy` script should checkout a `java` project and run some `maven` commands on it.

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'node' found among steps...
```

This used to work before some changes, but I couldn't say what what altered.
Current version is `2.147`
I found it might be a `Jenkins` plugin issue but nothing more

Answer (score 1):

It may be a blind shot here, but I would check [Nodes and Processes plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#node-allocate-node)
configuration in Jenkins (is plugin enabled? is plugin installed?). Also I would check if other steps which are part of this plugin like *sh* are working as expected.